# Wrong color applied to background of WebBrowser control in mfc

Tags: mfc, webbrowser-control

I am using webbrowser control in my MFC application. I have to change the background color of webbrowser control by selecting color from a color picker like color dialog. For this I am using CColorDialog class of MFC to select color. And getting selected color my using GetColor() function of CColorDialog class. 
My problem is that most of the time color applied as background color is different than selected color in color dialog.
Any idea what is going wrong???

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved this issue. Problem was that I was passing COLORREF value provide by GetColor() function of CColorDialog, but webbrowser accepts html hex code value. So I have converted COLORREF value to html hex code value by using following code:

```
CString sTemp;
COLORREF clr = clrDlg.GetColor();
sTemp.Format("#%X%X%X",GetRValue(clr),GetGValue(clr),GetBValue(clr));
```